# How can I use @font-face with Gotham-Light font?

Tags: html, css, font-face

I want to show Gotham-Light on the web with css codding but I can't code. I have two fonts named Gotham-Light.eot, Gotham-Light.ttf. Now How can I use on the browser? Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

Define your font like this:

```css
@font-face{
   font-family: gotham-light;
   src: url('gotham-light.ttf') url('gotham-light.eot');
}
```

And use it as you would normally

```css
#someelement {
    font-family: gotham-light;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'GothamLight';
    src: url('/fonts/Gotham-Light.eot');
    src: url('/fonts/Gotham-Light.otf') format('opentype'),
         url('/fonts/Gotham-Light.eot?iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/fonts/Gotham-Light.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/fonts/Gotham-Light.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/fonts/Gotham-Light.svg#gothamlight') format('svg');}
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesnt apply to IE, but FF and Chrome you can do this

```css
@font-face{
font-family: gotham-light;
src: url('gotham-light.ttf');
}
```

or

```css
@font-face{
font-family: gotham-light;
src: url('gotham-light.eot');
}
```

then apply the font-family to whatever class you want in css